# MSSQL convert varchar with custom format to date

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting

I read a CSV with `BULK INSERT`. In this CSV I have dates formatted with `MMM yyyy`(e.g. `Jan 2016`).

What is the best way to convert this varchar to a date column?

---

So far I only found solutions using the in-built formats. None of these formats match my format. Also note that the missing `day` should get the value `01`. This leads to following conversion:

`Jan 2016` -> `2016-01-01` (format of second date doesn't actually matter. I normally use `yyyy-MM-dd`)

Comment: Did you try to set date format before import? [SET DATEFORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-dateformat-transact-sql)
By the way this works as you want, too
`SET LANGUAGE us_english;`
`SELECT CAST('Jan 2016' AS date)`

Comment: I'm not sure there is a way to do this within the `bulk insert` itself.  You could insert the `MMM yyyy` field into a `varchar` field, then do the conversion in a separate step (e.g. either an `update myTable set myDate = CONVERT(DATE, '01 ' + myPseudoDate, 106)`, or insert all records from your staging table to a new table, using the same conversion logic.

Comment: @serge the import worked fine after setting the language. You can put it as answer. But now I would be interested if there is any way to find out the previous language...

Answer (score 1):

NB: For the one step solution, please see [@Serge's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53186954/361842); the proposed solution there does work even without the day component of the date.

---

## Original Answer

I'm not aware of any way to do this within the `bulk insert` statement itself.  However, to do it as a 2 step process is fairly straight forwards:

1. Import the data into a varchar column:

   ```
   bulk insert MyDatabase.dbo.MyStagingTable  
   from '\\server\share\data.csv';
   ```
2. Then convert the varchar to a date.  This could be done as an update statement; though it's more likely you'd want the import to be done to a `staging` table, then the conversion done when moving that data from the staging to the actual table.

   ```
   insert MyDatabase.dbo.MyActualTable (RealDate /*, ... */)
   select convert(date, '01 ' + myPseudoDate, 106) /*, ... */
   from MyDatabase.dbo.MyStagingTable
   ```